# Number of element used in dynamic memory allocation in c++

Tags: c++

I heard that when I use dynamic memory, the number of elements allocated is saved in the four bytes before the first element. How can I access to this number?

for example:

```
node* nn=new node[5];
```

So, how can I find `"5"` in `nn-1` or something like this?

Comment: Implementation defined. That 5 may be nowhere near the memory block allocated.

Comment: The C++ Standard Language has no such guarantees.  The memory allocation scheme is compiler or OS dependent.

Comment: you can't do this, and it may or not actually be true that it works, but it's an implementation detail and not something you should concern yourself with. You should wrap the array creation and keep track of size yourself.

Comment: If you need to access size of array in the place where is it unknown, then probably you want to use some container like vector or array from STL

Answer (score 0):

It is true that some old OSes/compilers could save the size just before the allocated block. But that's ancient times and certainly not something to rely upon.

Reading before an array is just undefined behaviour.

Good news for you: you can get the feature you want by

- dropping those old `new []` statements
- use `std::vector`: safer, auto deletion when out of scope, possible boundary checking, etc.. AND way to get the size.

example:

```
std::vector<node> nn(5);
nn[3] = node(xx,yy);
cout << "size: " << nn.size() << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The undefined behavior method is:

```
Node * node_block = new Node[5];
// The following is undefined behavior
uint8_t * pointer = (uint8_t *) node_block;
pointer -= 4U;
printf("[0]: 0x%02X\n"
       "[1]: 0x%02X\n"
       "[2]: 0x%02X\n"
       "[3]: 0x%02X\n",
       (unsigned int) pointer[0],
       (unsigned int) pointer[1],
       (unsigned int) pointer[2],
       (unsigned int) pointer[3]);
```

Again, this is undefined behavior and anything could happen, including incorrect values.